# Count days in each month for week overlapping two months

Tags: r

If I had a sequence of weeks, does anyone know of a way to count the days in each corresponding months for a given week, using R.

So if I had a sequence :

```
week commencing
"2015-04-22" 
"2015-04-29" 
"2015-05-06"
```

How could I create the following:

```
week commencing   Days in starting month   Days overlapping
"2015-04-22"       7                         0
"2015-04-29"       3                         4
"2015-05-06"       7                         0
```

I am aware of the lubridate package which has a number of useful associated functions but can't think how to apply them to get the above result.

Comment: I imagine that using the `POSIXlt` version of date sequences would allow the separate consideration of 'month' and 'week' for each date.

Comment: @BondedDust Yes you can easily add columns for a month or week using month(object) or week(object) from the lubridate package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dates<-as.Date(c("2015-04-22","2015-04-29" ,"2015-05-06"))
f<-Vectorize(function(d){
  sum(as.POSIXlt(d+0:6)$mon==as.POSIXlt(d)$mon)  
})
```

Result:

```
> data.frame(Start=dates,ThisMonth=f(dates),NextMonth=7-f(dates))
       Start ThisMonth NextMonth
1 2015-04-22         7         0
2 2015-04-29         2         5
3 2015-05-06         7         0
```